# single return of ternary operator

Tags: javascript, ternary-operator

I wonder if possible to write ternary operator for single return. I tried google online, but couldn't find an answer. or it doesnot called ternary operator??

Thank you very much for your advice.

`If(A == 1) execute_function(); into A == 1 ? execute_function()  //???Possible???`

Comment: Why? The ternary just isn't appropriate here in my opinion.

Comment: Sorry, i am a noob, so we dont use ternary operator  in this way?

Comment: why not just execute_function(exists); ?

Comment: I have updated, I want to execute only if A == 1

Comment: Same logic though, execute_function(A == 1);

Comment: @Till You can consider ternary operation as an alternative to if-then-else. So, instead of writing `if(condition) doSomething else doSomethingElse` you can write `condition ? doSomething : doSomethingElse` In your case you have just the if condition, while the else is empty, so as @Lloyd wrote ternary is not appropriate in your case

Comment: if execute_function(A == 1), how about the parameter going into the function??? I am no use A.....

Comment: @mardavi Thanks for expanding, should have said that really.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

yes:

```
(exists == 1) ? execute_function() : false;
```

runs function if exists is true else wont

Added:
Doing just like following would be better:

```
if( A == 1 ) {
  execute_function();
}
```

As using ternary operator in above case is not so fruitful, as you are checking only for the true side of the condition and do not care about what's in the false side.

Comment: @Till yes, you need to use false side as well, you can use blank string like '', or 0 or false

Comment: Had exactly the same dilema and figured out `(statement) ? true : null;` works just as fine

Comment: I still argue that in this case ternary just isn't appropriate, you're not gaining anything by using it.

Comment: @Lloyd yes you're correct, have updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 24):

Here is the shortest way.

```
A == 1 && execute_function();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
condition ? (runTrue) : (runFalse);
```

is available in javascript.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 1):

As someone already mentioned, `A == 1 && execute_function();` is the shortest. However, another option is to use a single line if statement:

`if( A == 1 ) execute_function();`